# How to forbide creation a variable inside a function with the same name as the class level variable?

Tags: android-studio, dart

Is it possible on IDE level to forbide creation a variable inside a function with the same name if that name already defined in this class?

```
...
double _bmi;

String calculateBMI() {
  double _bmi = weight / pow(height / 100, 2);
  ...
```

Comment: It's not prohibited by the language. I do not think there is a [lint](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/) for it either, so most likely the answer is currently "no".

Comment: Why do you want to forbid it?

Answer (score 0):

```
double _bmi;

String calculateBMI() {
  double _bmi = weight / pow(height / 100, 2);
```

This won't bother you as much coz the first _bmi is accessible using an object only, while the _bmi in the function calculateBMI() is **local** to that function so no outside function can access _bmi inside CalculaedBMI().

ex:

```
void main() {
  Test obj = Test();
  print(obj.bmi);
  print(obj.temp());
  print(obj.temp2());
}

class Test {
  int bmi = 10;

  int temp() {
    int bmi = 20; //this is local to this function
    return bmi;
  }

  int temp2() {
    return bmi;
  }
}

o/p:
10
20
10    //**see that the class level bmi still holds its value so its unaffected**
```